# Problem with django nose and south having multiple databases

Tags: python, django, django-south

I had a django project with one database (default). South was installed for generating migration scripts and nose as a test framework. Models were built on this database. All tests were run successfully.

Subsequently, I needed to connect a second database (legacy), which I also added to the DATABASES configuration. I access this database using raw sql and no models. While trying to run the previously running tests, I noticed that:

1. nose also creates a test database for the legacy database
2. default django tables (auth_... etc) are also created in this database
3. south runs all migration scripts against the legacy database as well and fail to do so

What I would like is to disable the creation of the test legacy database and the running of the migration scripts on it. Ideally, I would like to create tables in the test legacy database myself by issuing raw sql create-insert statements. Is that possible?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your path of least resistance is probably to write your own test running management command.  To do so you can either override the existing command or simply create a separate command with your desired behavior.

The docs for creating custom management commands can be found on the official [django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) and you can find a decent example of overriding the stock "test" command in the [django-test-extensions](https://github.com/jezdez/django-test-extensions) project.